# Voting Period App

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

What is the best way to implement a voting feature in my SharePoint Site?

Periodically, the administrator will be creating polls for users to be able to cast votes on fellow employees and colleagues.

My searches have suggested the use of the survey system, however I would like a simpler voting feature than a survey. A simple list of candidates and a vote button for the user to click, that will tally all votes on a selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using surveys for this.